# VSCode - Choose from random settings on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure vscode in such a way that each time it starts up, it uses a different font and theme, from among the ones that are installed?

I have searched around but the closest I found was about changing fonts for different parts of the code (using developer tools and CSS), which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: When we changed default It also work for every time.